# when do effective line bundles have uniformly bounded H^1?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

For which smooth projective varieties $X$ (say, over $\mathbb{C}$) is it true that $h^1(X,\mathcal{O}_X(D))$ is bounded above, where $D$ ranges over all effective divisors on $X$?

Comment: Example: $X$ of Neron-Severi rank one, because for $D$ of high enough degree the $h^1$ will vanish. Non-example: $\mathbf{P}^1\times \mathbf{P}^1$ or $G/B$ (use Borel-Weil-Bott in the latter case).

Comment: @PiotrAchinger I don't think P1xP1 is a nonexample. Effective divisors on P1xP1 are O(a,b) where a,b>-1. Kunneth says these line bundles satisfy h1(O(a,b))=0. Perhaps you missed the effective hypothesis?

Comment: Suppose X is Fano, and the pseudoeffective cone equals the nef cone. Then any effective divisor D is nef, and thus we can write D=K_X+(-K_X+D). The second term is necessarily ample, thus by Kodaira vanishing we have h1(D)=0.

Comment: In particular these hypotheses apply when X is rational homogeneous (e.g. G/B)

Comment: @YosemiteStan of course my comment was nonsense, thank you!

Comment: A remark: for any surface $S$ and any irreducible curve $C\subset S$ with $C^2<0$, $h^1(\mathcal{O}_S(nC))$ is unbounded (by Riemann-Roch).